# Replacing missing values in Juila

Tags: julia

I have data-frame contain some missing values, I want to replace all the missing values with the mean of LoanAmount column

```
df[ismissing.(df.LoanAmount),:LoanAmount]= floor(mean(skipmissing(df.LoanAmount)))
```

but when I am running above code i am getting

```
MethodError: no method matching setindex!(::DataFrame, ::Float64, ::BitArray{1}, ::Symbol)
```

Comment: you can use Impute.jl package to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Zeeshan, please don't edit questions to ask something completely different. Przemyslaw's answer appearently was the right one, and now appears rather odd if one does not look at the edit history. There's not probably at all with asking a second, follow-up question.

Comment: @Bogumil, i want tor replace missing values with mean and mod, but not able to do that, i tried with impute package but is using interpolation for treating missing values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `skipmissing` e.g.:

```
mean(skipmissing(df.LoanAmount))
```

Answer to the second, edited question: you should broadcast the assignment using the dot operator (`.`) as in the example below:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(col=rand([missing;1:3],10))                                                      
10×1 DataFrame                                                                                         
│ Row │ col     │                                                                                      
│     │ Int64?  │                                                                                      
├─────┼─────────┤                                                                                      
│ 1   │ missing │                                                                                      
│ 2   │ 3       │                                                                                      
│ 3   │ 2       │                                                                                      
│ 4   │ 2       │                                                                                      
│ 5   │ missing │                                                                                      
│ 6   │ missing │                                                                                      
│ 7   │ missing │                                                                                      
│ 8   │ 3       │                                                                                      
│ 9   │ 1       │                                                                                      
│ 10  │ 3       │                                                                                      
                                                                                                       
julia> df[ismissing.(df.col),:col] .= floor(mean(skipmissing(df.col)));                                 
                                                                                                       
julia> df                                                                                              
10×1 DataFrame                                                                                         
│ Row │ col    │                                                                                       
│     │ Int64? │                                                                                       
├─────┼────────┤                                                                                       
│ 1   │ 2      │                                                                                       
│ 2   │ 3      │                                                                                       
│ 3   │ 2      │                                                                                       
│ 4   │ 2      │                                                                                       
│ 5   │ 2      │                                                                                       
│ 6   │ 2      │                                                                                       
│ 7   │ 2      │                                                                                       
│ 8   │ 3      │                                                                                       
│ 9   │ 1      │                                                                                       
│ 10  │ 3      │
```

### Impute.jl

yet another option is to use `Impute.jl` as suggested by Bogumil:

```
Impute.fill(df;value=(x)->floor(mean(x)))
```

Comment: `Impute.fill` uses `mean` by default so if you need `mean` you do not have to specify it (assuming you have a float column).

Answer (score 1):

I found this one also,
when we need to replace with mean

```
replace!(df.col,missing => floor(mean(skipmissing(df[!,:col]))))
```

when we need to replace with mode

```
replace!(df.col,missing => mode(skipmissing(df[!,:col])))
```